Why is GNU wget only returning an index.html.tmp file, instead of the actual files I want?
I want to download a lot of satellite data (organized by each day of each year) in .hdf format from NASA's LAADS DAAC archive. They have a helpful guide that provides a code sample to use with GNU wget and it works very well:
wget -e robots=off -m -np -R .html,.tmp -nH --cut-dirs=3 "https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/PATH_TO_DATA_DIRECTORY" -- header "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN" -P TARGET_DIRECTORY_ON_YOUR_FILE_SYSTEM

The issue is that this approach is very heavy-handed. I want to only download files from the data directory that include the string h19v05. After reading the GNU manual and reading other questions on this site, I edited the recommended code sample for pattern recognition:
wget -e robots=off -m -np -A "*h19v05*" -R .html,.tmp -nH --cut-dirs=3 "https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/PATH_TO_DATA_DIRECTORY" -- header "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN" -P TARGET_DIRECTORY_ON_YOUR_FILE_SYSTEM

However, this only returns an index.html.tmp file and then promptly removes it:
Length: 188259 (184K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'C:/Users/seyon/Desktop/thesis/tilesets/years/2007./MCD19A2/2007/index.html.tmp'
MCD19A2/2007/index.html.tmp   100%
[=================================================>] 183.85K  1.16MB/s in 0.2s
Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2024-07-04 05:30:49 (1.16 MB/s) - 
'C:/Users/seyon/Desktop/thesis/tilesets/years/2007./MCD19A2/2007/index.html.tmp' 
saved [188259/188259]
Removing C:/Users/seyon/Desktop/thesis/tilesets/years/2007./MCD19A2/2007/index.html.tmp since > it should be rejected.
FINISHED --2024-07-04 05:30:49--
Total wall clock time: 23s
Downloaded: 1 files, 184K in 0.2s (1.16 MB/s)

I then tried the originally recommended code sample, and it started to work again. But again, this approach recursively downloads all the files in the data directory, which means that I have to download hundreds of unnecessary files for each day of each year. Is my added syntax or format incorrect?

It's probably something to do with how the archive is organized, but without access to that it's hard to do more than guess.
